# How long should my non-Jewish friends burn in hell for?

Tags: death, gehinnom

I've always been told that no matter how evil I was, at worst I would burn in hell for 11 months. Well, 12 months if I was really bad.

Today I was looked this up on Wikipedia, and it confirmed the Rule of 11 Months,

> The overwhelming majority of rabbinic thought maintains that people are not in Gehinnom forever; the longest that a Jew can be there is said to be 11 months (unless he is a fully wicked person, in which case 12 months), however there has been the occasional noted exception.

My questions pertains to non-Jews though. Recently in one of my conversations with one of these people (non-Jews) I was talking about how long they would burn in hell for. I don't believe it's fair to have the same duration applied to both Jews and non-Jews: how long will non-Jews burn in hell for?

Comment: Why do you equate punishment in the afterlife with burning in hell, and why do you assume that a non-Jew will, by default, be subject to punishment after death?

Comment: A non-jewish person will be rewarded for the good that he has done and punished for the bad. There are those who say that the *burning* is the realization what has been done wrong and how he should have befaved. This applies to Jews and nonJews. The idea of *burning in hell* is a Christian idea that we do not follow.

Comment: @sabbahillel So, with regard to hell, what special perks am I entitled to for honoring the diet and picking the bacon off my sandwhich?

Comment: for just picking the bacon off, you aren't entitled to anything. The sandwich has to burn in hell.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where that Wikipedia article gets its information from, but the Talmud in various places discusses eternal punishments.

One of these places is in [Rosh Hashana 17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rosh_Hashanah.17a.5?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he) where it discusses that certain sins are so severe that (even if) Hell will end, these sinners will continue to be punished.

Point being that how reward and punishment are meted out is beyond human understanding.

What we do know is that Gcd is just, and everybody gets punished for every one of their wrongdoings - the severity of the punishment being decided upon by Gcd taking all factors into consideration.

So too, even the smallest Good Deed is rewarded; with Gcd deciding how much reward.

What exactly these rewards and punishments are, is beyond our understanding. We're physical beings and we're discussing spiritual rewards and punishments. There's no way we can get our head around it. The Talmud uses analogies that we can relate to, like "getting dipped into boiling dung". Obviously in the spiritual afterlife there's no dung, no pots and probably no fire. It's all about spiritual punishment.

The closest you can get to it is when you're put down and feel like dirt, or praised and feel like a million dollars. You're the same size, but your spiritual essence is reacting.

So while you may be right that The Chosen Nation gets preferential treatment (details unknown to me), as members of The Chosen Nation we also have a lot more obligations. Your non-Jewish friend has a mere 7 commands to deal with; we can get rewarded & punished for 613!

Comment: "I don't know where that Wikipedia article gets its information from" - the part about 12 months is obviously from [Eduyot 2:10](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91_%D7%99) and the part about 11 months is probably an inference from the common custom to say kaddish for 11 months. Wikipedia's "the occasional noted exception" is probably a reference to the source you bring